# Copy-pasting versus entering "alter user "root"@"localhost" identified by ..."

Tags: mysql, macos, terminal

I've **copied-pasted** `alter user "root"@"localhost" identified by "NEW PASSWORD";` into `mysql>`. The message is:

> Query OK, 0 rows affected (0,00 sec)

But if I **enter** exactly the same command (tested several times!), the message is:

> ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the > >manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'indentified by "NEW PASSWORD"' at line 1

Why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please take a closer at the error the server returns; you're typing *i**n**dentified* instead of *identified*!

Comment: Sometimes you do not see the simplest things. Thank you very much!